# Codename one showNativePicker() method issue

Tags: java, oop, codenameone, lwuit

I am using showNativePicker() in my Calendar application and when I am selecting a date it will only display current date so how can I manage it to display selected date in showNativePicker() method? Thanks in advance.

**This is my code:-**

```
    try{
           Display.getInstance().showNativePicker(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,PivDisplayCalendar.this, value, metaData);
           Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Date", value);
           Log.p(value.toString());
           Dialog.show("Selected Date", value.toString(), "OK", "");
   } 
           catch(Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: The [class documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#showNativePicker-int-com.codename1.ui.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) shows that method returning a value. Passing `value` as a parameter has no effect on the subsequent state of variable `value`

Comment: But when I am printing value in a log then it will display the current date. @spacepickle

Comment: I mean use something like `value = ...` see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23622491/2842227) for why you shouldnt use this method directly though

Comment: I am testing this project on physical device and the native picker is also working properly But, I just want to ask is there any method which is use to display selected date through picker.

Answer (score 2):

You are not capturing the value returned by the call to `showNativePicker()`

Here is an example piece of code. Notice the assignment statement in the second line. You may need to cast/convert this as the method returns `Object`

```
try {
  value = Display.getInstance().showNativePicker(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,PivDisplayCalendar.this, value, metaData);
  Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Date", value);
  Log.p(value.toString());
  Dialog.show("Selected Date", value.toString(), "OK", "");
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```